# D3 Line graph not drawing my path from CSV data

Tags: d3.js

I am having some trouble. I am trying to make a simple line graph using D3 with data from a csv file that has dates and values.

I've attached my code below.. The problem I am having is that it won't draw a line for me. At first, I thought my data needed to be in an array as some of the other examples online have that, but others simply do as I did and it works fine. If it needs to be in array format, how does one go about doing that? and if not, any idea what might be wrong?

Any help would be great :)

```
    //setup
var margin4 = {top:10, bottom:30, right:10, left:30};
var height4 = 400 - margin4.top - margin4.bottom;
var width4 = 600 - margin4.right - margin4.left;

var svg4 = d3.select(".fuel")
    .append('svg')
    .attr("height", height4 + margin4.top + margin4.bottom)
    .attr("width", width4 + margin4.right + margin4.left)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin4.left + "," + margin4.top + ")");


//get the data and make line


d3.csv("Weekly Fuel Prices.csv", function(data){

        //x-axis with the date
        var x4 = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) {return d.date;}))
            .range([0,width4]);
        svg4.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height4 + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x4));

        // y axis with prices
        var y4 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })])
            .range([ height4, 0 ]);
        svg4.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y4));

    console.log(data);


        //line 
        var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x4(d.date) })
        .y(function(d) { return y4(d.value) });

        // Add the line
        svg4.append("path")
            .data(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "grey")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr('d', line);
    }
)
```

Comment: I don't know what your csv file looks like, but assuming its not a problem with your data structure, what if you change ```svg4.append(line).data(data)``` to ```svg.append(line).datum(data)``` Notice the ```datum``` verse the ```data```

Comment: You don't want to bind each item in the data array to an element, so you want to use `datum()` or alternatively an array of size one: `.data([points])`. I know there are better answers out there, but I'm having trouble finding one, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61415303/7106086) one's a few days old and the first half should address your issue. I'm sure there's a good canonical somewhere though.

Comment: thanks so much for your responses - i tried datum (and played around with some of the other formatting), and I've got it up and running :) thanks again!